# Has anyone used firephp with firefox 4 and Zend Framework DB Profiler?

Tags: php, zend-framework, firebug, firephp, zend-db-profiler

I can't see the log in the console. The headers show the log, but nothing show up on the console. I've tested the Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug and everything works fine.

Any tips?

Comment: I have not worked on Firefox4 (but on 3.6 ) , but did you forgot to enable the console / scripts ?

Comment: That's strange, I've restarted the tabs and the browser and checked the scripts tab also. After a while, it worked. You can post as answer if you want.

Comment: its buggy for me. Sometimes it works, but it slows everything down to the point where firefox was becoming useless. I just turned it off.

Comment: Works for me most of the time. Try juggling with display filters for the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not worked on Firefox4 (but on 3.6 ) , but did you forget to enable the console / scripts ?